# UCMA 4.0 - using Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration.Sample.Common not existed

Tags: lync-2013, ucma

I am a newbie in Lync and currently developing an application by Lync UCMA 4.0. But when I add reference **Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration** and using *Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration.Sample.Common;* occured error:

> The type of namespace 'Sample' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration' (Are you missing an assembly reference?)

I had added

> Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration

into my project.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are following an example as Sample.Common is not a member of the Microsoft.Rtc.common namespace.

The Sample.Common namespace appears in a number of Microsoft example and is usually created as part of the tutorial.

Have a look at the following for a code listing for UCMAHelper class in the Sample.Common namespace https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh527753(v=office.14).aspx